# logging in using twitter api in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, twitter

I am developing an application in which I will supply my twitter username and password to login to twitter account.I had seen [twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#dotnet) API's ,But that wouldn't helped me out because none of them contains any executable code on Visual studio.The `.sln` files are also not working.Anyone who can help me in providing a sample code.
Thank you in meekness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this turtorial [C# Twitter Client](http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/dotnet/twitterclient.aspx)

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

This article on CodeProject should set you in the right direction.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247336/Twitter-OAuth-authentication-using-Net

Here is another good article on setting up your Twitter authentication as well.

http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2009/03/twitter-oauth-with-net/